# Why can't I connect to a remote actor system?

Tags: scala, akka, remoting

I am trying two connect to different local Akka `ActorSystems` remotely. I am using Scala 2.11.1 and Akka 2.3.3.

My application.conf looks like this:

```
akka {
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote-RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2552
    }
  }
}
localConf {
  akka.remote.netty.tcp.port = 8448
}
remoteConf {
  akka.remote.netty.tcp.port = 4224
}
```

The `Actor` is pretty straight forward.

```
import akka.actor._

class Consumer extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg: String => println("Received: " + msg)
  }
}
```

For the remote system I am using:

```
import akka.actor._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object RemoteStart extends App {
  val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  val system = ActorSystem("remoteSystem", config.getConfig("remoteConf").withFalBack(config))
  val actor = system.actorOf(Props[Consumer], name = "consumer")
}
```

And finally the code of my local system:

```
import akka.actor._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object LocalStart extends App {
  val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  val system = ActorSystem("loaclSystem", config.getConfig("localConf").withFallBack(config))
  val actor = system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://remoteSystem@127.0.0.1:4224/user/consumer")
  actor ! "test"
}
```

I would expect that it will print `Received: test`. But instead I get error messages. But instead I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.ActorSelectionMessage.wildcardFanOut()Z
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have conflicting versions of Akka on your classpath. NoSuchMethodErrors are almost always caused by that.

Comment: Actually I had conflicting versions of many libraries in my classpath. After deleting the SBT cache and reimporting the really nessecary libraries, it all worked just perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the akka-remote module to your build file?

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/intro/getting-started.html